# Hibernate computed properties

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following Hibernate entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs")
public class Job {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "jobs_j_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "jobs_j_id_seq", name = "jobs_j_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "j_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "j_description", length = 300, nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "j_category", length = 50, nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private JobCategory category;

    @Column(name = "j_job_provided", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String jobProvided;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "j_provider_id")
    private User provider;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "job")
    private Set<Review> reviews;

    @Transient
    private Long averageRating;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

What is the correct way of computing the value of the averageRating variable? I've read about `@Formula`, but I understand this only works the first time the entity is fetched. Meaning that if a new review is added to the Job instance, JPA will update the job but the `@Formula` will not run again, leading to my value not being recomputed.

Is there a way of having a dynamic `@Formula`, that will react to changes?

I can always iterate through the reviews and calculate the averageRating, but as we all know this is not the way to go.

Comment: could you use a persistent column for averageRating?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to denormalize the schema, you can add an actual column on the table and handle the update with SQL triggers. Then you just annotate the property with `@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)` and Hibernate will after every update refresh that property. This might work with `@Formula` as well, but I would advise against this. What is the point of having this average? IMO you should just always compute it on demand and think about storing it only if that becomes a performance issue.